# Custom IdentityUserRole duplicate columns for RoleId and UserId

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have a custom my custom identity classes setup like so;

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int, AppUserLogin, AppUserRole, AppUserClaim> { }
public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
public class AppRole : IdentityRole<int, AppUserRole> { } 
public class AppUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { } 
public class AppUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }
```

And whenever I run recreate my database it always comes up like this picture below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any idea what is causing this? Do I have to set this up using the Fluent API? I did this before and I don't see on my other project the need to do that.

Comment: Yes, because your entities are named `App.....` and the fields don't have this prefix. The default naming conventions can't resolve foreign keys, you have to map them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Well like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(ApplicationUser).HasMany(p => p.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(p => p.UserId); 
modelBuilder.Entity(ApplicationRole).HasMany(p => p.Users).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(p => p.RoleId);
```